# About http request and request

Tags: request, httprequest

I'm trying to understanding `HTTP` request and requset concepts.

**What does mean "`HTTP` request"?** My undesrtanding is following:

I think that "`HTTP` request" is just char sequence which is serialized to ASCII byte stream and transfering via network. From the standardized of ASCII implies that on server-side this ASCII byte sequences will be deserialized in a correct char sequnces and independent from what means are implemented client and server sides.

But **what about request?**

I think that request is no more than abstraction by means of which client and server are communicated in a client-server model. This abstraction satisfies that request can be sended to server and server can be get a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does mean "HTTP request"?

[HTTP is a protocol.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) An HTTP request is defined by the protocol, specifically in [RFC 2616 §5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5). It is not "just" a char sequence. It is a sequence of characters sent from a computer (which is, by definition, the client) to another (which is, by definition, the server), and this sequence must conform to the spec.

> But what about request?

In what context are you using "request" for anything *other* than a shorthand for "HTTP request?"

Comment: _In what context are you using "request" for anything other than a shorthand for "HTTP request?"_ There is no context of using. I want to understanding model of client-server communication more formally. Like set theory in mathematics in which we doesnt get defenition of "set" but we can provide properties and methods to work with him. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no definition more "formal" than the spec.

Comment: I'm understand your post about http request, many thanks. But now i want to realize with "abstarct" request. Is there exist, for example a finite-automata model of client-server communication in which take a part request/response as state-transitional function (for example). I hope it's help me to realize.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but I'm pretty sure the answer is no – if for no other reason that HTTP is a stateless protocol.